# php best practices for returning multiple lines of content in an IF statement

Tags: php, html, wordpress, if-statement

I am writing a php plugin for wordpress. I'm trying to be mindful of clean coding and want to know the best practice for returning several lines of HTML code in an IF statement.

Obviously I know about `echo` but I thought I had seen a technique like this used, but it doesn't seem to work for me. The idea being that you create several $content variables and then return it outside of the IF statement.

```
function signup() {
    if(!Skizzar_Registration::is_skizzar_site_active()) {
        $content = '<div class="signup">';
        $content .= '<h1>Sign up</h1>';
        $content .= '</div>';
    } else {
        $content = '<div class="signed_up">you are already signed up</div>';
    }

    return $content;

}
```

Currently though this returns nothing when I call the function

Comment: Are you sure it's not returning anything? Have you tried using `var_dump()` on the returned data?

Comment: The code looks good.

Comment: @Expodax yes your right, var_dump was returning something, I found that if I changed return $content to echo $content it worked. So the issue was actually with how I called the function (doh!). Is it better to keep return $content and then use echo signup() to call the function, or use echo $content and then just use signup(); to call the function?

Comment: `/*return $content;*/ echo $content`

Comment: I'd say return the data and echo it outside of the function.

Comment: @Expodax done! Thanks for helping out with that

Comment: In general programming, i would also return and leave display up to the caller. However in wordpress there is something of a convention - see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already discovered, the specific issue is that you are not ecxhoing the data.

As per your followon question (which is prefered, return or echo), in wordpress there seems to be a convention where both options are offered with the functions named accordingly:

```
//echos
function the_signup_form(){
    echo get_the_signup_form();
}

//returns
function get_the_signup_form(){
    if(!Skizzar_Registration::is_skizzar_site_active()) {
        $content  = '<div class="signup">';
        $content .=     '<h1>Sign up</h1>';
        $content .= '</div>';
    } else {
        $content  = '<div class="signed_up">you are already signed up</div>';
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: That is an interesting observation, and true what you say. However, I think on this occasion, since the plugin is purely for my use, I will keep it with just the one function and save on lines of code!

Comment: Sure, its just preference. However adding two lines of code (excluding the closing brace) for the echo version doesnt exactly add much bloat!

Comment: No problem. Just one further point, i find it helps readability a lot to line of your html fragments.